# boost::hash doesn't work for c string?

Tags: c++, boost

boost::hash certainly works for std::string, but does it work for c string?
I've tried following code but the `charHash(s2)` result changes every time I run the program. It seems boost::hash takes effect on the address of s2 instead of "Hello", so the hash result varies with the random address allocated by OS.

```
std::string s = "Hello";
char *s2 = "Hello";
boost::hash<std::string> stringHash;
boost::hash<char *> charHash;

cout << stringHash(s) << endl; // always "758207331"
cout <<charHash(s2) << endl;   // it varies
```

Comment: Because it's hashing the value of the pointer, which should be random at each execution of the program?

Comment: @WiSaGaN that's what I guessed. I'm looking for a way to hash on c string.

Comment: Just use `std::string` version of the hash by using `stringHash(std::string(s2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/hash.html):

> As it is compliant with TR1, it will work with:
>
> - integers
> - floats
> - pointers
> - strings
>
> It also implements the extension proposed by Peter Dimov in issue 6.18 of the Library Extension Technical Report Issues List (page 63), this adds support for:
>
> - arrays
> - std::pair
> - the standard containers.
> - [extending boost::hash for custom types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html).

Basically, it is hashing the pointer. If you must hash a C-string, you could:

```
std::cout << stringHash(std::string(s2)) << std::endl;
// or the uglier...likely not equivalent
std::cout << boost::hash_range(s2, s2+strlen(s2)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: boost::hash_range() is what I'm looking for. Thanks!